# Insert text based on the highlight color in a MS Word file

Tags: vba, ms-word, highlight

I am trying to analyse Word files where **chunks of text have been highlighted by users** in a set of colors, in order to check whether there are patterns in the color of highlighted texts.

I use the selection.Find loop to match the colors of interest and then **insert a text mark** when the highlight begins and ends.

Files have unevenly highlighted chunks of texts in the same sentence, sometimes with no characters between a color change

```vb
Sub clickforcolors()
'Finds highlighted text and inserts text before and after displaying the color
'Find some highlighted text:
    With selection.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
        .Text = ""
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Highlight = True
        Do
            .Execute
'Check that it's the colors we want
        Loop Until selection.Range.HighlightColorIndex = wdYellow Or selection.Range.HighlightColorIndex = wdRed Or selection.Range.HighlightColorIndex = wdBrightGreen _
          Or Not .Found
'Select that chunk and insert the text needed according to the color
        selection.Range.Select
        If selection.Range.HighlightColorIndex = wdYellow Then
            selection.InsertBefore (" /// BegginingY")
            selection.InsertAfter (" EndY ///")
        ElseIf selection.Range.HighlightColorIndex = wdRed Then
            selection.InsertBefore (" /// BegginingR")
            selection.InsertAfter (" EndR ///")
        ElseIf selection.Range.HighlightColorIndex = wdBrightGreen Then
            selection.InsertBefore (" /// BegginingG")
            selection.InsertAfter (" EndG ///")
        End If
    End With
'make sure that the cursor is at the end of the selected text, so that running this macro again will find another text:
    selection.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd

End Sub
```

This works for one chunk of colored text. I'd be okay to use the macro 30 times per file if it worked.

There are two issues

1. the code has only been working on the **red** chunks.
2. it doesn't work when there are two **different colors in the same sentence**.
   I know this issue has to do with range, but I haven't found any other option to manage it.

Answer (score 0):

I've ran into a similar problem recently. Fixed it with Sentences instead of Range and using wildcards with .Text="*".

Hope it helps